# Compiling dust.js template to html server side?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

Is it possible to compile `dust.js` template to plain html?

I tried dusty and dustc serverside compilers but they generates a javascript file which will write the content of the template on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to render a dust template directly to HTML, but it is not recommended. Anyway, this can be done with [pyv8](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) a Python bindings for V8 JS engine. 
In this [article](http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/integrating-python-and-javascript-with-pyv8/) Andrew Wilkinson show how he made it for mustache.js.

Answer (score 1):

Dust only compiles to JavaScript, but you can use a compiled template to render plain HTML. This works the same on the server and on the client. On the server you need to use Node.js or Rhino (or some other engine that interprets JavaScript).